# Rearranging multiple selected listview items after user finishes drag & drop

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

### INTRODUCTON:

I am working on a drag and drop feature of the listview. I am stuck at the last step -> rearranging *multiple* selected items after user finishes drag and drop.

### QUESTION:

Can you explain me the algorithm that implements item rearrangment?

*I have the index of the clicked item after user releases the mouse. I have indexes of dragged items and their count. Pseudo code is acceptable as well, but be warned that I might have follow up questions.*

NOTE:

This post has been edited in response to the comments that claimed my original question did not seek user friendly implementation.

The point is to implement standard drag & drop behavior, and the reason I phrased my question poorly at the first place was my lack of experience with this topic.

*If further clarifications are required I will update my post.*

Regards.

Comment: Isn't the post order supposed to be 1,5,6,2,3,4 - and not 1,6,5,2,3,4 like in your paint example?

Comment: No, it should be 1,6,5.... The user is trying to swap {2,3,4} with 6, and leave 5 where it is.

Comment: You said you made it work when the selected items need to swap up? How did you do that?

Comment: Got it, though I must admit this is a highly unintuitive UX. When you do such a thing in most UIs, you expect the selected block to move to a new place, not to move the underlying object that happens to be there back to the place where your selection was. What if you select a few items with gaps in between them? This will become awkward.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see the problem in just making a new array, putting all items in the correct order there, then modifying your ListView. It would be much cleaner than any swapping code that will cover all the end cases of such an operation.

Comment: @EldadMor: *Isn't the post order supposed to be 1,5,6,2,3,4 - and not 1,6,5,2,3,4 like in your paint example?* This is my first time trying to implement drag and drop, I don't know what I am doing. I tried finding examples but found only one on CodeProject. That one crashes when selected 1000 items, according to comments from that article. I do not know how to implement the behavior you described, although I agree with you that logical result is the one you said and not mine. Should I just delete the question or edit?

Comment: @EldadMor: I have edited my question in response to your comments. I wish my users to have good UX, and the reason my question was poorly phrased is due to my inexperience with this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal drag & drop reordering removes the selected items and reinserts them in the new spot. It would be pretty unintuitive for the existing items in the new spot to jump to where the old ones came from.

To implement "standard" reordering, basically you:

- Remember the index of the item below where the user drags your items to. In your example above, this would be `5` (assuming the new items are to be inserted **above** Item 6)
- Remove the dragged items from the list one at a time using `LVM_DELETEITEM`
- If the dragged items were originally **above** the new position, subtract the total number of dragged items from the index you remembered in step 1. This would give us `2` using the examples above.
- Finally, reinsert the dragged items at the remembered index (remembering to increment the new index for each additional item). For example, the first dragged item would be inserted at position `2`, then the next at `3` and so on.

Also note you need special handling for the case where the items are dragged to the top of the list. In that case, you would start the insertion at `0`, then `1` and so on.